# Embedded Google Calendar incomplete event loading

Tags: google-calendar, embed

I have a public Google Calendar that displays events like a list.

See (right side of container): http://www.ucmbookstore.com/SiteText.aspx?id=11055

My problem is that I have events in the calendar, but they aren't showing up by default. I have to click "Look for more" in order to load events, because apparently it will only show a month ahead of the current date, and the only dates I have entered are ones that are 2-3 months away. Is there a way to modify this interval of loading events, to say 2-3 months ahead?

It's one more step for the visitors to go through to click this link, and I'm suspecting some miss it altogether and just assume we don't have any events entered.

Comment: I don't know, I see events for March, April, and May. A setting for the individual user, perhaps? You're dealing with the API, no? That's primarily a programmer problem and rather off-topic here. You might have better luck looking in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-calendar.

Comment: Well I'm using the web app to configure the widget, so it made sense to be under web apps. Could make a case for either site I suppose.